# {{did-update}} fall into infinite loop in ember js

Tags: ember.js, ember-concurrency

I need to get store data when some properties change. Property value exist in the service, so I re-execute function using {{did-update}}.
But this action fall into infinite loop when the service property value changes.

This is my code.

- **js** file

> ```
> export default class CurrentApplications extends Component {
>
>   @service store;
>   @service current;
>   @service permissions;
>
>   @tracked currentApplications = emberA([]);
>
>   constructor() {
>     super(...arguments);
>     next(()=> {
>       this.currentApplications.pushObject(this.loadCurrentApplications.perform());
>     });
>   }
>
>   @task
>   *loadCurrentApplications() {
>     const query = {
>       page:     this.currentApplications.length + 1,
>       per_page: 10,
>       from:     moment().subtract(1, 'minutes').format(),
>       until:    moment().add(1, 'minutes').format(),
>       state:    ["accept", "assigned", "cancelled", "superseded"]
>     };
>
>     const locationId = this.current.locationId;
>     if (locationId) query.location_id = locationId;
>
>     if (get(this, 'current.user.isStaff')) {
>       set(query, 'user_ids', get(this, 'current.user.id'))
>     }
>
>     return yield this.store.query('shift-application', query);
>   }
>
>   @lastValue('loadCurrentApplications') currentApplicationsCurrentPage;
>
>   @task
>   *loadForNewLocation() {
>     this.currentApplications.clear();
>     this.currentApplications.pushObject(this.loadCurrentApplications.perform());
>   }
>
>   get applicationsLoaded() {
>     return this.currentApplications.length &&
>            !this.currentApplications.lastObject.isRunning;
>   }
>
>   get hasMorePages() {
>     return this.currentApplications.length &&
>            !this.currentApplications.lastObject.isRunning &&
>            this.currentApplicationsCurrentPage.meta.page < this.currentApplicationsCurrentPage.meta.pages;
>   }
>
>   @action
>   nextPage() {
>     this.currentApplications.pushObject(this.loadCurrentApplications.perform());
>   
> }
> ```

- **hbs** file

> ```
> {{did-update (perform this.loadForNewLocation) this.current.locationId}}
> <div class="columns is-multiline dashboard__sidebar__row mb-0">
>   <div class="column is-12">
>   ...
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

When the **this.current.locationId** changes, **loadForNewLocation** fall into loop execute.
How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this, in your template:

```
(perform this.loadForNewLocation)
```

`loadForNewLocation` accesses tracked data, `this.currentApplications`, which means that when `this.currentApplications` changes, the `(perform)` helper re-runs (because helpers auto-track).

To get around this, you'll want to change your did-update callback to (instead of being the result of the perform helper), to something like this:

```
{{did-update this.getNewLocations this.current.locationId}}
```

where

```js
getNewLocations = () => {
  this.loadForNewLocation.perform();
}
```

For more information about this problem, I have a more in-depth write up here:
https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/ember-resources/issues/340#issuecomment-1028533534

Comment: The link above was definitely helpful. Great article. Anyway I had another problem. When I wrap {{did-update}} with <div>, the problem was solved. Can you tell me about the difference between using {{did-update}} alone and using it wrapped with <div>?

Comment: can you open another question with code snippets? (and link it back here) I'm not sure I understand  (I do have a hunch though)